# adding markers and infowindow without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to place multiple markers on a map. For this, I followed this procedure

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?csw=1

[Demo](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-autocomplete)

But here, once user starts typing for another marker, then first marker is getting replaced by the second marker. For this, I initialized the marker inside autocomplete function so that it creates another marker as user enters second one. This worked fine. Another marker is getting pinned. But onclicking the marker, it will not produce infowindow since the infowindow is inside autocomplete function.

I need infowindow for all markers.

```
<script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                    mapOptions);

            var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('searchTextField'));
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

            autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map
                });
                infowindow.close();
                marker.setVisible(false);
                input.className = '';
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
                    input.className = 'notfound';
                    return;
                }

                // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                    map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
                }
                var address = '';
                if (place.address_components) {
                    address = [
                        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                    ].join(' ');
                }
                marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
                }));
                if (address.length != 0) {
                    address = place.name + ', ' + address;
                } else {
                    address = place.name;
                }
                marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                marker.setTitle(address);
                marker.setVisible(true);

                infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + marker.title + '</strong><br>');
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });



        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Here infowindow will not work since there is no action listener for this. so I wrote the below code.

```
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
```

But it wont work as marker is out of scope variable here. How to do this? Please help

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Move the event listener inside the function that creates the marker?

Comment: No, the function gets called when user enters text in textbox. So, infowindow will not work when he stops typing.

Comment: Use a createMarker function to hold function closure on the infowindow content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a createMarker function to hold function closure on the infowindow content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null; 
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function createMarker(place) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map
                });
                // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                    map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
                }
                var address = '';
                if (place.address_components) {
                    address = [
                        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                    ].join(' ');
                }
                marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
                }));
                if (address.length != 0) {
                    address = place.name + ', ' + address;
                } else {
                    address = place.name;
                }
                marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                marker.setTitle(address);
                marker.setVisible(true);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
                  infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + marker.title + '</strong><br>');
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
}

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                    mapOptions);

            var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('searchTextField'));
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

            autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);



            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                infowindow.close();
                input.className = '';
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
                    input.className = 'notfound';
                    return;
                }
                createMarker(place);
            });



        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_markerOnClickWithInfowindowA.html)